# Is there a neater way to do this? C++ IF

Tags: c++, arduino

Is there a neater way to do this bit of code?

It just checks if all wires are connected & if they're not then pint fail on the LCD that's attached to the arduino.

```
  //Check if all wires are connected
if (digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW){
 if (digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW){
   if (digitalRead(wire_RED) == LOW){
    if (digitalRead(wire_GREEN) == LOW){
      if (digitalRead(wire_BLUE) == LOW){
        if (digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) == LOW){
          if (digitalRead(wire_GREY) == LOW){
            if (digitalRead(wire_WHITE) == LOW){
              if (digitalRead(wire_BLACK) == LOW){
                lcd.print(pass);
                delay(3000);
                lcd.clear();
                lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
                testPassed = true;
              } else lcd.print(fail);
            } else lcd.print(fail);
          } else lcd.print(fail);
        } else lcd.print(fail);
      } else lcd.print(fail);
    } else lcd.print(fail);
  } else lcd.print(fail);
 } else lcd.print(fail);
} else lcd.print(fail);
```

Comment: Put them in a single if statement condition and "and" them together.  That is, use the && operator.

Comment: Are `wire_BROWN` etc numeric values and could you potentially iterate over them via a `for` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put it in a function to make it more readable:

```
bool all_wires_low()
{
    return
        digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_RED) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_GREEN) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_BLUE) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_GREY) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_WHITE) == LOW &&
        digitalRead(wire_BLACK) == LOW;
}

// elsewhere:
if( all_wires_low() )
{
    lcd.print(pass);
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
    testPassed = true;
}
else
{
    lcd.print(fail);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When having multiple variables, it's always simpler to enumerate them in a way that allows you to loop through them instead of having to write repetitive code. I personally like to organize them in a separate file, it's much neater that way and easier to add new values -

```
typedef enum {
#define DEF_WIRE(x) WIRE_ ## x,
#include "wires.def"
} wire_types;

int main() {

    bool testPassed = true;
    for (int wire = 0; wire < WIRE_MAX; ++wire) {
        testPassed &= (digitalRead(wire) == LOW);
    }
    if (testPassed) {
        lcd.print(pass);
        delay(3000);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
    } else {
        lcd.print(fail);
    }
}
```

where wires.def has:

```
DEF_WIRE(BROWN)
DEF_WIRE(ORANGE)
DEF_WIRE(RED)
DEF_WIRE(GREEN)
DEF_WIRE(BLUE)
DEF_WIRE(PURPLE)
DEF_WIRE(GREY)
DEF_WIRE(WHITE)
DEF_WIRE(BLACK)
DEF_WIRE(MAX)
#undef DEF_WIRE
```

A side benefit is that it allows you to do something cool like this:

```
const char* wire_names[] = {
#define DEF_WIRE(x) #x,
#include "wires.def"
};
```

and then

```
printf("wire %s is LOW\n", wire_names[wire]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'and' operator, `&&`, to combine multiple conditions:

```
if (digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_RED) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_GREEN) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_BLUE) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_GREY) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_WHITE) == LOW &&
    digitalRead(wire_BLACK) == LOW){

  lcd.print(pass);
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
  testPassed = true;
} 
else {
  lcd.print(fail);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
if ( (digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW) && (digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW) && ... /* other checks */)
{
   lcd.print(pass);
   delay(3000);
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
   testPassed = true;
}else
{
   lcd.print(fail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's get a single signal that answer's question:
is all signals low or at-least one of them high.
This answer is provided by simple '&' toggle is guaranteed to combine all signal's to produce one signal and provide a definite answer for the question - are all signals low?

The result of that signal is compared with LOW.

```
  if((digitalRead(wire_BROWN)  &
    digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) & 
    digitalRead(wire_RED)    &
    digitalRead(wire_GREEN)  &
    digitalRead(wire_BLUE)   &
    digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) &
    digitalRead(wire_GREY)   &
    digitalRead(wire_WHITE)  &
    digitalRead(wire_BLACK) ) & LOW)
    {
    ....
    ...
    }
```

Comment: but using `&` instead of `&&` means *all* the `digitalRead()` call have to be executed where as `&&` stops at the first failed call.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use && to shorten your code. Also if your wire vars are on the same PORT, you might be able to AND (&) them.

Anyways:

```
if(digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW && digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW && ... ) {
   lcd.print(pass);
   delay(3000);
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
   testPassed = true;
} else {
   lcd.print(fail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `and` operator `&&`, since it *short-circuits* the `if` *statement* becomes `false` as soon as any call to `digitalRead` fails to return `LOW`:

```
if ((digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_RED) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_GREEN) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_BLUE) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_GREY) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_WHITE) == LOW) &&
    (digitalRead(wire_BLACK) == LOW)) {
                lcd.print(pass);
                delay(3000);
                lcd.clear();
                lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
                testPassed = true;
    } else {
        lcd.print(fail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Boolean variables and logic:

```
bool all_wires_connected = true;
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_BROWN) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_ORANGE) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_RED) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_GREEN) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_BLUE) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_PURPLE) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_GREY) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_WHITE) == LOW);
all_wires_connected = all_wires_connected && (digitalRead(wire_BLACK) == LOW);
if (all_wires_connected)
{
    lcd.print(pass);
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
    testPassed = true;
}
else
{
    lcd.print(fail);
}
```

This may encourage the compiler to use conditionally executed instructions.

Comment: Using the `&&` operator may also encourage the compiler to use conditionally executed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is kind of embedded systems, I recommend investigating the content of the `digitalRead()` function or macro.

The code looks like each wire color is represented as a bit inside an integer.  There is a simple method for testing if all bits are set or cleared (depending on the representation of `LOW` or `HIGH`).

For example, if `LOW == 0`, then you could read the wires value and compare against zero (one `if` statement).  A zero value read means all bits are zero, thus all wires would be LOW.

One `if` statement would be easier to manage than 9 `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution would be to put them in an array:

```
int allWires[] = { wire_BROWN, wire_ORANGE, wire_RED, wire_GREEN, wire_BLUE, wire_PURPLE, wire_GREY, wire_WHITE, wire_BLACK };
```

and then iterate through them:

```
testPassed = true;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(allWires)/sizeof(int); i++)
{
    if (digitalRead(allWires[i]) == LOW)
        testPassed = false;
}

if (testPassed)
{
    lcd.print(pass);
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Status: ARMED");
}
else
    lcd.print(fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bit mask, and boolean AND it with your port:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BitMask

btw. reading ports is:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

---

the mask will look like follows:
00011111
where the 0 is for all the bits connected to something else than the colored wires and 1 is what you want to test for...

you will be using two ports so:

```
byte MASK2 = some bit pattern depending on wire arrangements;
byte MASK1 = some bit pattern depending on wire arrangements;
int PORTA = 
if(( MASK1 & PIND + MASK2 & PINB ) == 0)
{
    //code
}
```

this answer must be equal to 0.